# Differentiation and complex value

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If the value of $f(z_0)$ or $f^\prime(z_0)$ is complex number then is $f(z)$ analytic at $z_0$?

Answer (score 1):

$f (z) $ is analytic at a point if it is *differentiable* at the point , *and* on some region containing the point.

Answer (score 0):

No. But if $f(z)$ is differentiable as a 2D real function and its derivative $f'(z)$ is expressible as a complex number, and that is true for all points in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then $f$ is holomorphic or analytical in that open set and thus in $z_0$.